# Where are HTML general entities defined?

Tags: html, xml, dtd, doctype

From the [HTML DTD](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd):

```
<!ELEMENT A - - (%inline;)* -(A)       -- anchor -->
<!ATTLIST A
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED  -- char encoding of linked resource --
  type        %ContentType;  #IMPLIED  -- advisory content type --
  name        CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- named link end --
  href        %URI;          #IMPLIED  -- URI for linked resource --
  hreflang    %LanguageCode; #IMPLIED  -- language code --
  target      %FrameTarget;  #IMPLIED  -- render in this frame --
  rel         %LinkTypes;    #IMPLIED  -- forward link types --
  rev         %LinkTypes;    #IMPLIED  -- reverse link types --
  accesskey   %Character;    #IMPLIED  -- accessibility key character --
  shape       %Shape;        rect      -- for use with client-side image maps --
  coords      %Coords;       #IMPLIED  -- for use with client-side image maps --
  tabindex    NUMBER         #IMPLIED  -- position in tabbing order --
  onfocus     %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element got the focus --
  onblur      %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element lost the focus --
  >
```

Which file defines what these entities are, for example `%LinkTypes;` or `%Script;` ?

Comment: Have you searched inside the linked file? They are defined at the top. Search for `LinkTypes` (without the `%` and `;`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [linked HTML DTD](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd) are [entity declarations](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-entity-decl) such as

```
<!ENTITY % LinkTypes "CDATA"
    -- space-separated list of link types
    -->

<!ENTITY % Script "CDATA" -- script expression -->
```

Given these declarations, you can see that both `%LinkTypes;` and `%Script;` expand to `CDATA` (character data); the comment provides some additional guidance on their intended form or use.

Comment: @khughes -- I see, if it's nothing more than character data, why even define those entities then?

Comment: They provide useful organization structure to communicate intent beyond what's enforced or enforceable in the DTD.